# php mysql select query

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

i have multiple drop list box that contain data from the database so i want to select the second drop list based on the section of the first one
the first table have these three fields 
**district_id(primary key),district_name, governorate_id(foreign key)**
second table has these three fields 
**village_id(primary key), village_name, district_id(foreign key)**

so i want the user to select the district box first then based on the select district name that have an id i want that the second box display all the village name that have a village.district_id = district.district_id.
can anyone help me??
i was selecting each table independent from the other one but i need it to be based on the first one

## chunk of the code

```
function districtQuery(){

$distData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM districts");

  while($recorddist = mysql_fetch_array($distData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recorddist['district_name'] .  '">' . $recorddist['district_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}
// function for select by village
function villageQuery(){

//$villageData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM village");

  $villageData = mysql_query("SELECT village_name FROM village WHERE district_id = ('SELECT district_id FROM districts')") or die (mysql_error());

  while($recordvillage = mysql_fetch_array($villageData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recordvillage['village_name'] .  '">' . $recordvillage['village_name'] . '</option>';

  }


}
```

Comment: Could you show us the code you have? It's easier to help if we have something to work with.

Comment: ok i will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a server side call and populate the 2nd dropdown based on the selectyion of the first.

[php + populate drop down menu on the selection of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129695/php-populate-drop-down-menu-on-the-selection-of-another?rq=1)

Comment: @ karmafunk neither of these had help me i did not understand how to use ajax with mysql and php ??

Comment: So this is where you need to take some time out to learn the ajax concepts.  Follow this tutorial and you will have a better understanding and be able to complete your code.  Once you know how to do you will always know. http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

#### Here i described two types of selected query

```
$query = "select * from table_name";
```

above one select the whole table

```
$query = "select * from table_name where id = 1";
```

above one select the particular record only